# How can i use select tag in Onsen-UI?

Tags: cordova, select, drop-down-menu, onsen-ui, phonegap-cli

I am building design for a mobile application using Onsen UI ,
i just want to make a select menu as like we have in simple html :

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
.
.
</select>
```

Since i am working on a registration form ,i want list all country name and let the user select the choice.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Of course!  Onsen is a UI Framework so it adds JS and CSS.  Just add your HTML as normal.  I did this codepen for you:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwdXxE

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot . i already tried this but i just wanted that the form looks all the same design

Comment: So in the onsenui.css file is all the formats.  If you are using material or flat, find that for textboxes and such and just create your own class to style the select.  Also, if you go here:  http://components2.onsen.io/ find the object that has the right style and click on the actual item.  The CSS will popup in a box so you can copy it.